# How to access a member object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, object

I have made a custom object called students that has two nsstring object. One is for the name and the other for the student id. If I try to pass the custom object to something that takes nsstring, it doesn't work. I want to pass the name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **nest your method calls** like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[studentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
```

Or if you defined your members as properties and want to access them via dot-notation:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [studentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].name;
```

The only issue with the dot-notation approach is the compiler will most likely give you warning that it couldn't find the property `name`, so you will need to cast it to the appropriate data type before accessing the property via dot-notation.